# Show that $\delta(at)=\left(\frac{1}{|a|}\right)\delta(t)$.

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

The unit impulse function $\delta(t)$ is defined in terms of the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t)\delta(t)dt=x(0)$$
where $x(t)$ is any test function that is continuous at $t=0$. Show that $\delta(at)=\left(\dfrac{1}{|a|}\right)\delta(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int x(t)\delta(at)dt=$$
$$\int x(\frac{t'}{a})\delta(t')\frac{1}{a} dt'=$$
$$\frac{1}{a}\int x(t'/a)\delta(t')dt'=$$
$$\frac{1}{a}x(0/a)=\frac{1}{a}x(0)=$$
$$\frac{1}{a}\int x(t)\delta(t)dt$$

You can get the absolute value of $|a|$ with using that $x(-0)=x(0)$ and $\delta(t)=\delta(-t)$ so the sign of $a$ does not matter.

Comment: Sorry, the explanation about the sign is not so convincing. It rather means that the result could have any sign. And by the way, how do you know that $\delta(t)=\delta(-t)$ ? (This is a kind of circular argument with $a=-1$.)

Comment: Yes, I agree with Yves Daoust's comment. We can't use the fact $\delta(t)=\delta(-t)$ in the proof.

Comment: From the definition in the question you can see that $\delta(t)=0$ $\forall t \neq 0$ But maybe you do not need this to show the $\frac{1}{|a|}$ term

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you.

Comment: @Matthias I don't understand why does $\int x(t) \delta(at) dt = \frac{1}{|a|} \int x(t) \delta(t) dt$ implies $\delta(at)=\frac{1}{|a|} \delta(t)$? Please teach me. Thank you very much.